# How to rearrange the excel columns by the columns header name

Tags: excel, vba

How could I rearrange the columns by the columns header name.
I need to process a report on weekly basis,the raw worksheet has 23 columns.I abstract a part of them as example.

Raw columns sequence：   `QTY       Payment Terms       Contract No.   etc`
Desired columns sequence:`Contract No.     Payment terms        QTY     etc`

Any idea how to automatize the columns rearrangement with VBA code?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to arrange the column headers to be in alphabetical order? If so, use the sort function.

Comment: Your best bet is using tables. Insert a table into your data range and then the first row will be your headers. Through built-in functions for tables you can select the whole column using only the header e.g. `Activesheet.listobjects("table1").listcolumns("mycolumn").range` if you share a code and show what you are trying to do we can help more specificly

Comment: My abstracted example might be sort of misleading,In total there are 23 columns,I need to arrange them in a desired sequence,not in a alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this work for you? I tried with just four columns, and it worked for me.

```
Sub rearrange_Columns()
Dim correctOrder() As Variant
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim headerRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim mainWS As Worksheet

Set mainWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Edit this to be the correct order you need
correctOrder() = Array("Column A", "Column B", "Column C", "Column D")
' Now, we know that the number of headers you have to rearrange are `UBound(CorrectOrder)+1`


With mainWS
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set headerRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
End With

Dim newWS As Worksheet
Set newWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
newWS.Name = "Rearranged Sheet"

Dim col As Long
With newWS
    For col = 1 To lastCol
        For Each cel In headerRng
            If cel.Value = correctOrder(col - 1) Then
                mainWS.Columns(cel.Column).Copy .Columns(col)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next col
End With

End Sub
```

Note: There's no real error handling, so if your headers need to be `TRIM()`ed or checked for erroneous info, you'll need to add something that does that.

[image]

Comment: @Max - Yay! Glad to hear it helped.  (You can mark it as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows)