# VBA Array, rearrange columns by header name “Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range”

Tags: excel, vba

The following code executes nicely, however throws the following error- “Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range”. Using the code from: [How to rearrange the excel columns by the columns header name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529391/how-to-rearrange-the-excel-columns-by-the-columns-header-name) , I added my 10 headers into the array in the order that I want them sorted. I have 149 header columns and 10 items in the array. I don’t know how to tell it to stop when the last value in the array is found and copied. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub Rearrange_Columns()
    Dim correctOrder() As Variant
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim headerRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim mainWS As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    correctOrder = Array("COUNTER", "day", "mon", "year", "hr", "min", "sec", "CAT1", "DOG1", "TIK")
    
    With mainWS
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set headerRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
    End With
    
    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Set newWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    newWS.Name = "Rearranged Sheet"
    
    Dim col As Long
    With newWS
        For col = 1 To lastCol
            For Each cel In headerRng
                If cel.Value = correctOrder(col - 1) Then
                    mainWS.Columns(cel.Column).Copy .Columns(col)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cel
        Next col       
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps `For col = 1 To UBound(correctOrder) + 1` instead of `For col = 1 To lastCol`

Comment: What line gives the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Match` to locate the column without looping through them.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Rearrange_Columns()

    Dim correctOrder() As Variant
    correctOrder = Array("COUNTER", "day", "mon", "year", "hr", "min", "sec", "CAT1", "DOG1", "TIK")
    
    Dim newWS As Worksheet, i As Long, v
    Set newWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    newWS.Name = "Rearranged Sheet"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To UBound(correctOrder)
            v = Application.Match(correctOrder(i), .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsError(v) Then
                MsgBox "'" & correctOrder(i) & "' not found", vbExclamation
            Else
               .Columns(v).Copy newWS.Columns(i + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: — Thank you. That revision works perfectly. And thank you to all that took a look at it.